# C++: Convert string into vector where each element is a vector of that character

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector

Is there a way in C++ to convert a string into a vector of a vector of characters? Currently, I am doing this:

```
std::string guide = "ACGCAC"; 
std::vector< std::vector<char> > word(guide.begin(), guide.end());
```

However, normal ways of indexing (using .at()) and setting are not working. If I try and set an element with this vector to another vector (see below), it does not work.

```
word[loc] = bases; //where bases = std::vector<char> and loc = int
```

I am trying to do the equivalent of the Python code below, but in C++. Thank you for any insight.

```py
word = [[letter] for letter in guide]
```

Comment: What is the value of loc in your code? Does it give any error message?

Comment: It's the only way that I thought I could then later set a given element to a vector of multiple characters. Some elements would have one character, others many

Comment: Loc is an int within the range of the length of the original word

Comment: My error comes not from that assignment itself but from later trying to print individual elements of this via:         for (auto&& possibility : iter::product(word)) {
            //std::cout << possibility;
            for (auto&& poss: possibility) {
                std::cout << std::get<0>(poss)'\n';
            }

        } ----------> error: invalid range expression of type 'std::__1::tuple<std::__1::vector<char, std::__1::allocator<char> > &>'; no viable 'begin' function available

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> word(guide.begin(), guide.end());
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. You want each `char` in `guide` to be used to construct a `vector` of size 1, containing that single `char`. But actually what this does is try to construct a `vector` *from* that `char` - and there actually is a constructor for that: [#3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> ```
> explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```

That is, for your first character, `'A'`, you're not constructing a vector containing the char `'A'`, you're constructing a vector containing 65 `'\0'`s. This is because `char` is implicitly convertible to `size_t`.

Just do what you want to do manually:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> as_individual(std::string const& s) {
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> v;
    v.reserve(s.size());
    for (char c : s) {
        v.push_back({c});
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to then unpack the resulting std::vector<std::vector<char>> like Python's unpack (*) operator?

Comment: @compbio_user There is not, and really cannot be.